# Tkinter window in bottom right corner

Tags: python, screen, tkinter

Is it possible to display a Python Tkinter window in the bottom right hand corner of the screen? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You use the [wm_geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#wm.Wm.geometry-method) method of the window to specify the geometry (width, height, x and y location) of the window.

Comment: But would this also work on widescreens? If I specify the the geometry to put it in the bottom right hand corner of a regular screen, wouldn't it be in the wrong place for a widescreen?

Comment: @Zachary Brown: there is no limitation. It's up to you to pick the proper coordinates. You can specify coordinates relative to the right and bottom edge of the screen. For example, a geometry of "-100-100" places the upper-left corner of your window at 100 pixels up and to the left of the bottom-right corner.